# I'm using axios and useEffect to do my get request but it doesn't work when my page is loaded

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, axios

When i refresh the page, my object is empty but when i go back in the code, change something and save it, the request is made again, with no refresh, successfuly and contain the expected result.

````
 const [specialities, setSpecialities] = useState([])
 const getData = async ()=> {

   await axios.get(getURL).then((response)=>{
     setSpecialities(response.data)
     console.log(specialities, "specialeties are displayed here")
   })
 } 

 useEffect(()=>{
   getData()
 }, [])```
````

Here i remove the accolades in my useEffect and it works, my response is full when i reload but the request is made infinitely.

```
const [specialities, setSpecialities] = useState([])
const getData = async ()=> {

await axios.get(getURL).then((response)=>{
  setSpecialities(response.data)
  console.log(specialities, "specialesss")
})}

useEffect(()=>{
 getData()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For class component,

```
  this.setState(response.data)
     console.log(specialities, "specialeties are displayed here")
```

You cannot get the specialities data just after setting it. It takes some time to set the data.

The below code would work as we have a callback after setting the state.

```
  this.setState(response.data, function() {
    console.log(specialities, "specialeties are displayed here")   });
```

For functional component,

```
 useEffect(() => { console.log(specialities); },[specialities);
```

Comment: Thanks @Ritik, but when trying your method, i see this error in the console:  **State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().**

Comment: Oh yeah, this works fine with class components. for functional use,  useEffect(() => {
      console.log(specialities);
  },[specialities);